Delete the last space in multiple lines
I need to remove the last 1 space for multiple lines if there is a 1 space.
I found the reference but it does not work for last.
I did :%s/    ^  /
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6962474/1917217
for example
"this is the test line1 "
"this is the test line"
"this is the test line2 "
"this is the test line "
"..."

How do I get rid of the last 1 space for multiple lines if there is a 1 space?

Could you use :%s/ "$/"/ to make the  changes?

What exactly did you try? In what way did it fail? "It [does] not work" is not a very helpful description. The command in @Fanteria's comment should solve your problem (and should be posted as an answer).

You can use :%s/ "$/"/ to make the changes throughout the entire document, or :'<,'>s/ "$/"/ if you want to apply it only to the selected text.
To explain, $ matches the end of a line, and  "$ matches any line that ends with a space followed by a quote. This match is then replaced with just a quote. For more information, check the :help pattern-overview or the complete pattern help documentation.

A little bit of explanation would greatly improve your answer. You might want to explain that $ anchors to the end of line. A nod to :help pattern  may enable OP to come up with regular expressions on their own.

I tried to improve my answer. Thanks for the advice @Friedrich.

Just replace a space before a double quote with a double quote.
 :%s/\ "/"/


What's the backslash for in your pattern?

To escape a single space. Hm.. I guess the escape is unnecessary because the space does not have a special meaning. For some reason, I have been doing like that for some time... Not sure why :)

I see. It's needed for some commands, e.g. when setting options, not for :s though.

maybe :%s/ "/"/ also works
